# Are questions about SystemModeler on-topic?

Tags: discussion, policy

**UPDATE**

Since people don't seem to think that much discussion is needed, **let's make this a vote**.

**Instructions:** Vote on precisely one of the two posts below to decide whether SystemModeler-only questions should be on-topic or not.  Use only upvotes, no downvotes please.

*Note:* Questions about how to use SystemModeler from Mathematica (e.g. WSMLink) are on-topic.  This is about deciding whether SystemModeler questions *not related to Mathematica* will also be on-topic.  An example would be a question concerned solely with [Modelica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelica) code, not Mathematica code.

**If you believe more discussion is needed or the decision shouldn't be made yet, post an answer.**

---

*Original post below:*

It is time that a definitive decision should be reached on whether questions about [SystemModeler](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/) are on-topic for Mathematica.SE.  We need a meta post that clearly states the decision and can be linked to.  The current uncertainty is clearly bad.  People who help out with the review queues need to have a clear answer.

[There was a long discussion about this](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/413/are-questions-related-to-systemmodeler-on-topic), but no definitive conclusion has been reached.  The highest voted answers in that discussion concludes

> Weighing the pros and the cons I'd say we pick a wait-and-see approach.

After a wait of two years, it's time to re-evaluate this and reach a definite conclusion.

I was first going to make this a yes/no style vote, but I'm not convinced anymore that people wouldn't want to have some discussion, so I will not make it a vote yet.

Summary of relevant facts:

- There are 9 questions tagged [system-modeler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-modeler), asked over a period of nearly two years.
- Two of these mention Modelica code, one is about WSMLink (i.e. how to access SystemModeler from Mathematica), two are of the tech-support type (i.e. software doesn't work, can't set it up), two are closed, and the rest are general.
- All questions have been answered.
- There is one user, [Malte Lenz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/25/malte-lenz), who is providing most good answers.  He is one of the SystemModeler developers.  It appears that current SystemModeler expertise may be lacking among MSE regulars.  [jrhodin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/241/jrhodin), also a SystemModeler developer has also answered questions here.
- [Wolfram Community has 32 threads.](http://community.wolfram.com/content?curTag=system%20modeler)  Not all questions are answered.  Some threads are not questions but usage examples or short tutorials posted by WRI.
- It appears that there's clearly more SystemModeler activity on Wolfram Community, but not dramatically so. Generally, there is not a lot of visible SystemModeler activity online.

I think most people would agree that questions about how to access SystemModeler from Mathematica (WSMLink) will be on-topic.  This discussion is about whether all SystemModeler questions should be on-topic (including ones concerned with Modelica code).

Answer (score 18):

**Vote here if you believe *all* SystemModeler-related questions should be ON TOPIC.**

---

Personally I have only one concern about allowing SystemModeler questions here:

There is not enough SystemModeler expertise.  There's a risk that questions won't get answered and the asker will be disappointed.  Are we doing a disservice to users by allowing SystemModeler questions and implicitly promising answers?  Well, so far all questions have been answered here and it's not 100% clear that posting on W Community is a much better option.  So this is probably not a good counterargument.

SystemModeler questions are very rare and will probably make very little impact, so there's no harm in allowing them ...

I lean slightly towards making SystemModeler questions explicitly on-topic.

Comment: This is a very wise decision and I am very much in favour of it. I am sure I will post some SystemModeler questions soon

Comment: One may go so far as to see SystemModeler as a kind of GUI for interaction with Mathematica. The system analogy might carry quite far and I have seen Bayesian Networks being modeled with Modelica as well - so the interest may be growing eventually. TL;DR quite definitely favorizing your suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

**Vote here if you believe SystemModeler-only questions should be OFF TOPIC.**

---

I think Szablocs review of the *SystemModeler* issue is very clear and cogent. But I disagree with his conclusion. I am a strict constructionist and would prefer limiting this site to *Mathematica* alone. Here are my reasons (all mentioned by Szablocs).

- There is one user, Malte Lenz, who is providing most good answers. He is one of the SystemModeler developers. It appears that current *SystemModeler* expertise may be lacking among MSE regulars.

  What happens if he stops participating? I don't like having to depend on one person to do all the heavy lifting on a topic.
- *SystemModeler* questions are very rare and will probably make very little impact, so there's no harm in **disallowing** them.
- There's clearly more *SystemModeler* activity on Wolfram Community.

  I think Wolfram Community is the proper place for  *SystemModeler* questions.

Comment: I hijacked your answer a bit.  There wasn't a lot of discussion, so I thought a simple vote is better.  Do you think this is okay?  People who've already voted can modify their vote easily since the posts have been edited.

Comment: What you've done is fine with me.

Comment: @Szabolcs, m_goldeber, I think it makes sense to route people to Wolfram Community but keep the question here with a link to the cross-posting. I personally think the MSE format is cleaner and leads to more learning than Wolfram Community, but I think a WC posting is more likely to get attention from a dev. It's way past the point of anyone caring, but those are my two cents.